# Cursor texture anti aliasing and issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm trying to use Unity's cursor API to change the cursor when dragging an item from the player's inventory for example. The cursor does change, but the image is blurry due to anti-aliasing (presumably). The image is a simple 16x16 sprite that is not anti-aliased when shown in the game world but is when displayed as the cursor. Is there any way to turn anti-aliasing for the cursor off?

Also, when I run the game outside of the editor, the cursor image doesn't appear to work at all - it just displays some little dashes or some static.

The way I'm setting the cursor is like so:

```
texture = itemImg.sprite.texture;
Cursor.SetCursor(texture, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
```

Where `itemImg` is the UI Image that handles drags (the inventory slot)

Any help or advice is appreciated. Should I just ditch the Cursor API if it's going to have these issues? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into problems when using the Cursor API. Although there are things to try before calling the *"cursor image doesn't appear to work at all"* a bug.

- Make sure that the cursor *Texture Type* is set to *Cursor*.
- Set the *Filter Mode* to *Point(no filter)*.
- Finally, set the *Compression* to *High Quality*.

[image]

Note that your code:

```
texture = itemImg.sprite.texture;
```

shows that the `Texture` you are using is not set to cursor as the *Texture Type.* Define the `Texture` to use then follow the steps above to make the correct settings for the Texture. Don't use UI Image as the source of the mouse cursor.

```
public Texture2D texture;
Cursor.SetCursor(texture, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
```

If these does not solve your problem, use `CursorMode.ForceSoftware` instead of `CursorMode.Auto`.

Finally, assuming you still have problems with the Cursor API, just abandon it and simply make a fake cursor by setting a SpriteRenderer position to the mouse position.

```
yourSprite.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

Now, you have control over the quality of the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

- Use 32x32 sprite not 16x16.
- Change Texture type to Cursor
- Choose Point Filter
- Set Compression to None

Works perfect on Unity 2018.3

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in Unity 2019.3 by:

- Scaling cursor sprite to 32x32.
- Setting Max Size to '32'
- Changing the Texture Type to 'Cursor'
- Setting Filter Mode to 'Point (no filter)'

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by changing CursorMode.Auto to CursorMode.ForceSoftware

```html
    // Set mousecursor to sprite
    public Texture2D cursorTexture;
    public CursorMode cursorMode = CursorMode.ForceSoftware;
    public Vector2 hotSpot = Vector2.zero;
```

Then change this in the inspector as well :)